# SQL Self join & where

Tags: sql

I need a right solution to this SQL query, I was asked to show the names of managers and their employees where department ID is between 60 and 80.

```
select department_id, a.first_name as worker,b.first_name as manager
from employees a 
join employees b
  on a.manager_id = b.employee_id
where department_id > 60 
  and department_id < 80
```

Comment: Show us some sample data and desire output. What is wrong with current query? That info help us to find the right answer for you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Please edit your table link into your question. Please act on the previous comment.

Comment: If you have another question, create a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
 select a.department_id, a.first_name as worker,b.first_name as manager
 from employees a join employees b
 on a.manager_id=b.employee_id
 where a.department_id>60 and a.department_id<80
```

in where clause there is `a.department_id` at the place of `department_id` and for select there is the same change. otherwise there will be conflicting column name. we have to tell the sql which table, a or b, is used for select and where clause.

Comment: what is the difference with OP query?

Comment: in where clause there is `a.department_id` at the place of `department_id`  and for select there is the same change.
otherwise there will be conflicting column name . we have to tell the sql which table, `a or b` is used for `select` and `where` clause.

Comment: it works!! but now i don't need the names, i need to count the amount of workers for each manager and if the count is bigger than 2 show the table

Comment: for this you have to use `Group by` and `having clause` in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Could you show what error this is producing if it doesn't work correctly?

what I have found out so far is that you should set a. and b. for department_id as well, otherwise columns are ambigious: isn't clear department_id from employee a or employee b to take.

```
select a.department_id, a.first_name as worker,b.first_name as manager
from employee a join employee b on a.manager_id=b.employee_id where 
a.department_id>60 and a.department_id<80 and b.department_id>60 and 
b.department_id<80
```

refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm for more information.

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/home/%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%90/%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D?preview=hr_schema.pdf) this is the tables and my solution shows this error "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined"

Comment: That's a dead link as far as I can tell